# using sed to replace transcript id with gene id from a fasta head

Tags: sed

I Have a fasta file as such:

> ENSGACT00000000002.1 cdna scaffold:BROADS1:scaffold_154:1880:13338:1 gene:ENSGACG00000000002.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding

I am needing to swap the gene field with the transcript at the beginning of the line. I have tried and tried, but I have been very unsuccessful.

Anything helps!

Comment: So you want to swap the text before the first space with the text between "gene:" and the following space?

Comment: What about `'s/^\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(.*gene:\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(.*\)$/\3\2\1\4/'`  Try it here: https://sed.js.org/?gist=952f838ebba6eb8d4db63f8694751510

Comment: Hey! That works! Thank you so much, Jerry Jeremiah!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap the text before the first space with the text between "gene:" and the following space then there are four parts of the line that you need to capture:

1. `^\([^ ][^ ]*\)` is the first bit of text that doesn't contain a space - this becomes \1
2. `\(.*gene:\)` is everything from that first space up to the text `gene:` - this becomes \2
3. `\([^ ][^ ]*\)` is the text between `gene:` and the next space - this becomes \3
4. `\(.*\)$` is everything on the rest of the line - this becomes \4

Then you replace those 4 pieces with the same 4 pieces - just rearranged: `\3\2\1\4`

So the sed command would be:

> `sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(.*gene:\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)\(.*\)$/\3\2\1\4/' file`